# Datatables: How to show a message while data is exported (Excel, PDF, etc)?

Tags: javascript, django, datatables

I use DataTables buttons plugin to export my data to Excel, PDF, etc. But when many rows of data have to be exported the process sometimes takes a lot of time while the file is created, I like to show a message that indicates the download is in progress until the 'save as' window appears.

I only have implemented the standard buttons configuration in the inicialization of datatable.

Many thanks in advance for any idea or suggestion.

Comment: Have you tried searching for some online resources? [Like this one](https://medium.com/@martinsOnuoha/show-a-loading-animation-on-file-upload-17925b7bf300)

Comment: @ZombieChowder thanks for the suggestion I'll review it and back to share the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm using server side processing to get the data of my datatable I enabled the "Processing" and "bprocessing" options and customize the spinner with language' parameters as follows:

```
$('#my_table').DataTable({
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100], [10, 25, 50, 100]],
        "columnDefs": [
            { "className": "dt-body-center", "targets": "_all" }
        ],
        "responsive": true,
        "processing": true, 
        "bProcessing": true,
        "autoWidth": false, 
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "url",
        "aaSorting": [2, 'desc'],

        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "language": {
            "sProcessing": '<i class="fas fa-asterisk fa-spin fa-6x fa-fw"></i> 
             <br>PROCESSING <br> Please wait...',
            },
           },
        dom:
            "<'row'<'col-sm-4'B><'col-sm-4 text-center'l><'col-sm-4'f>>" +
            "<'row'<'col-md-12'tr>>" +
            "<'row'<'col-md-7'i><'col-sm-5'p>>",

            buttons:[
            {
                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                text:'<i class="fas fa-file-excel fa-lg"></i>',
                titleAttr: 'Exportar a Excel (XLSX)',
                className:'btn btn-success',
                title:'DAWPs Data',
                action: newexportaction,
            },
            {
                text:'<i class="fas fa-sync"></i>',
                titleAttr: 'Limpiar filtro',
                className:'btn btn-secondary',
                action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
                        dt.search('').draw();
                        dt.order([2,'desc']).draw();
                }
            },
        ],

    });
```

With these modifications now when I clicked on export to excel button the spinner is showed in the table body; according the information I found, this only works when you're using server side.